# Proving $(I -cP)^{-1} = I+ \left(\frac{c}{1-c}\right)P$ , $P$ idempotent matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, random-matrices

Given that a matrix $P$ is idempotent how to prove the following relation:
$$(I -cP)^{-1} = I+ \left(\frac{c}{1-c}\right)P$$ $c$ is any real constant.

Comment: $c$ is not ANY real constant .. $c\ne 1$ else the RHS doen't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's multiply these two matrices together:
$$(I-cP)\left(I+\frac{c}{1-c}P\right)$$
If we get $I$ as a result, then we know that they are inverses. Use the distributive property:
$$I^2-cP+\frac{c}{1-c}P-\frac{c^2}{1-c}P^2$$
Use idempotence of $I$ and $P$:
$$I-cP+\frac{c}{1-c}P-\frac{c^2}{1-c}P$$
Factor out a $P$ from the last three terms:
$$I+\left(-c+\frac{c}{1-c}-\frac{c^2}{1-c}\right)P$$
Use algebra to simplify:
$$I+0P=I$$
Thus, the two matrices we started with in the original product are inverses.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{aligned}
(I - cP)^{-1} &= I + cP + c^2P^2 + c^3P^3 + \ldots &\text{(Maclaurin series)}\\
&= I + (c + c^2 + c^3 + \ldots) P &\text{(idempotence)}\\
&= I + \frac{c}{1-c} P &\text{(geometric series)}
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: OK for $|c|<1.$  But if  $|c|\geq 1$ (and $c\ne 1,$ of course) and  if $p\ne 0$ then the  series will not converge.  E.g. if $P=I$ and $c=-1.$